# Parse XML file in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have XML from Android and I would like to parse it in my Windows Phone project. I can only get value of element name, but I need to go deeper and take:

- Polski
- szt ml

C#:

```
foreach (XElement level1Element in XElement.Parse(loadedStringXml).Descendants("string"))
{
    myText = level1Element.Attribute("name").Value;
}
```

And my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resource>
  <string name="CurrentLanguage">Polski</string>
  <string-array name="myTypes">
    <item>szt</item>
    <item>ml</item>
  </string-array>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get Polski, use levle1Element.Value.
To get szt and ml, use:

```
foreach (var item in level1Element.Descendants("item"))
    item.Value; // this contains szt and ml
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var polski = xDoc.Descendants("string").First().Value;
var items = xDoc.Descendants("item")
                .Select(i => i.Value)
                .ToArray();
```